# Pontryagin classes of Frame bundle

Tags: vector-bundles

Let $\xi$ be a vector bundle of rank $m$ and $Fr\left(\xi\right)$ the $SO\left(m\right)$-principal frames bundle associated to $\xi$. 
What is the link between Pontryagin classes of $\xi$ and $Fr\left(\xi\right)$?
Thanks!

Comment: They're the same.

Comment: thank! could you give me a reference please?

Comment: It depends on what your favorite definition of the Pontryagin classes of a vector bundle resp. a principal bundle are.

Comment: Thanks! could you give me a reference? please